# Who were the disciples of Suka Maharshi?

Tags: history, advaita, time

When is Suka Maharshi is said to have lived? What's his timeline?

What is the timeline of advaita guru parampara?
What is time of Garudapadacharya?
What is time of Govindapadacharya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advaita guru parampara begins with the deva-parampara (Narayana, Brahma), followed by the Rishi-parampara (vasishtha, shakti, parashara, vyasa, suka). After Suka, we turn to the manava-parampara of Gaudapada, Govindapada, Shankara.

This is how it is chanted - Advaita-Guru-Paramparā-Stotram

> नारायणं पद्मभुवं वशिष्ठं शक्तिं च तत्पुत्रं पराशरं च
>  व्यासं शुकं
> गौडपादं महान्तं गोविन्दयोगीन्द्रं अथास्य शिष्यम् ।
>
> श्री शंकराचार्यं अथास्य पद्मपादं च हस्तामलकं च 
> शिष्यम् तं तोटकं
> वार्त्तिककारमन्यान् अस्मद् गुरून् सन्ततमानतोऽस्मि ॥
>
> nārāyanam padmabhuvam vasiṣtham śaktim ca tat-putram parāśaram ca
> vyāsam śukam gauḍapāda mahāntam govinda yogīndram athāsya śiṣyam
>  śri
> śankarācāryam athāsya padmapādam ca hastāmalakam ca
>  śiṣyam tam totakam
> vārtikakāramanyān asmad gurūn santatamānato’smi ”

It is an anadi sampradaya. The above lineage is for this yuga. No historical timeline can be given because the dates of rishis can not be known. Even the dates of Gaudapada are controversial.

The fact that suka taught Gaudapada is mentioned in the famous Patanjali charitram and is given in detail in the book Voice of God by Sri Chandrashekarendra Saraswati Swamigal of Kanchi Math. The complete incident [is mentioned here.](https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/archives/advaita-l/2012-February/030925.html)